# Dynamic color changing in a Crystal Reports crosstab

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to know how we can have crosstab values dynamically change color.

What I did is in the background I have written a condition:

```
if {ESCROW_MASTER.EBM_NOTIFICATION_AMOUNT}>100.00 
then 
crred 
else 
cryellow
```

But this is applying to the whole page

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "it is taking to hole page", but if you want to dynamically change the values of the cross-tab values, you can use the following code for your formula:

```
If currentfieldvalue > 100.00 Then Red Else Yelow
```

Since you are probably summing up the values, but checking a single value of `EBM_NOTIFICATION_AMOUNT`, if the last value is greater than 100, it will make all of your cells red.  By using `currentfieldvalue`, the crosstab will always see what each individual cell's value is before determinig what color to use.

Comment: thanks for u r response i used formula as you said  but still its applying to all cells of EBM_NOTIFICATION_AMOUNT

Comment: @vijauuu -- is EBM_NOTIFICATION_AMOUNT even in the crosstab?  What version of Crystal Reports are you using?  Can you provide a screenshot of what is happening?